# Android-Car Media-App onPlayFromSearch not called in most cases

Tags: android, android-auto

I want to enable voice commands.

When i say 'play next station' -> ok onSkipToNext(...) is called

When i say 'play previous station' -> ok onSkipToPrevious(...) is called

When i say 'play blubber' (something undefined) -> ok onPlayFromSearch(...) is called

When i say 'play NDR 2' (a really existing radio station) -> nothing called in my app, but google say 'therefore you need to install tunein ....'

tuneis is a competitor to us.... what is going on?

I have no idea what todo... i would expect onPlayFromSearch will be called
everytime i say something like 'play ...'